# JQuery Toggle Slide – display element when other elements toggle closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slide

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncuacvcu/

**DIV home** is displayed by default.

When I click on **LINK one**/**LINK two**, **DIV one**/**DIV two** replaces **DIV home**. When I click on **LINK one**/**LINK two** again, **DIV one**/**DIV two** toggles shut, leaving an empty white space. How do I get **DIV home** to display again at that moment?

At the same time, if **DIV one** is open and I click on **LINK two**, I want **DIV one** to be replaced by **DIV two** (i.e. without going through **DIV home**).

Here's what I tried (and some variations), but I can't get it to work:

```
 $("a#one_toggle").click(function()
         {
           $(".hideall").not(".one").slideUp();
           $(".one")slideToggle(function(){
               if($('#client1').is(':visible')){
                   $('#client0').SlideUp();
               } else{
                   $('#client0').SlideDown();
               }
         });
 });
```

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the callback of slideToggle and check if the div with class home is visible or not then you show it.

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

http://api.jquery.com/is/

```js
$(function() {
    $("a#one_toggle").click(function() {
         $(".hideall").not(".one").slideUp();
         $(".one").slideToggle('slow', function() {
            showHome($('.one'));
         }); 
    });
           
    $("a#two_toggle").click(function() {
         $(".hideall").not(".two").slideUp();
         $(".two").slideToggle('slow', function() {
            showHome($('.two'));
         }); 
    });
});

function showHome(elementToCheck) {
    // now we know if the div to check is visible or not
    if (!$(elementToCheck).is(':visible')) {
        // the div is not visible so we show it
        $('.home').slideDown();
    }
}
```

```css
.one,
.two {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="one_toggle">link one</a>
<a href="#" id="two_toggle">link two</a>

<div class="home hideall">
  home
</div>

<div class="one hideall">
  one
</div>

<div class="two hideall">
  two
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to help you :)